# How to make Synaptic the default to install .deb files?

Tags: package-management, synaptic, default-programs

I have tried a lot and Ubuntu software center crashes the most when installing .deb packages with it. And I would like to make synaptic package manager as the default to open .deb installation files. How to set up synaptic as default package manager in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue with software center.

Right click on the .deb package and select properties. Click on the Open With tab, select synaptic and click set as default.

If synaptic is not available, you can install gdebi instead which is the recommended app to install deb packages by debian. You can install gdebi using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then, right click on the .deb package and select properties. Click on the Open With tab, select gdebi and click set as default.

Answer (score 6):

> ... And I would like to make synaptic package manager as the default to open .deb installation files. ...

Synaptic can not be used as the default program for DEB files, just like you want to.

But you can try gdebi.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Now you can set *gdebi* as the default application for DEB-files.

Comment: @NivedKannada Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Answer (score 1):

If App center crashes, alternatively You can Install it Using bash as:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

For further reference Check out official documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)

**To set as default:**
locate package in the file manager, right-click it, and select Properties then Click the "Open With" tab and select the application (Synaptic in your case) you want to use for pakages. Use the Set as default button to make the application the default application.

Comment: I already have Synaptic installed. I want to make it as the default to open and install .deb package files. Please correct your answer